# Exchange rate seems to be inconsistent. Some currency are do not show up, but are supported in some leve

Tags: coinbase-api

Look at: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-currencies

it states clearly "it can be defined as any supported currency". When I query the support currency DKK does not show up... but you can use DKK to get exchange-rate? Also the coinbase website shows my values in DKK.

So, what gives?!?! This is just confusing. I create a list with the support currency, but cannot choose DKK because it does not come in the query?!?!

anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you query all currencies, DKK is there:

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/currencies

RESPONSE {"data":[ ... ,{"id":"DKK","name":"Danish Krone","min_size":"0.01000000"}, ... ]}
```

You can also query just DKK to compare it with other currencies:

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=DKK

RESPONSE {"data":{"currency":"DKK","rates":{"AED":"0.54780095459776946093168", ... }}}
```

Comment: Thank you @Matija,
I found out that you are using the v2/currencies  which indeed does return DKK. I was using /currencies as specified by there documentation. Your answer help me.
thank you